Cargar al inicio una tabla con todos los resultados de una búsqueda inicial, con javascript
Estoy intentando hacer un programa que cargue una tabla con unos resultados obtenidos de una base de datos para hacer un buscador en tiempo real. Pero lo que no consigo es que cuando abre el programa, me cargue al inicio la tabla con todos los resultados de una búsqueda inicial. Lo que hace es que cuando escribo me va mostrando los resultados y si borro el contenido del campo de búsqueda, sí que me muestra todos los resultados. No consigo que me lea el primer SELECT del search_data.
search_data.php
---------------
<?php
    require_once("config/conectar.php");    

    $search_criteria = $_POST['search_criteria'];   

    if ($search_criteria == ""){
        $query = "SELECT * FROM personal";
    }
    else {
        $query = "SELECT DNI, Nombre, Apellidos, ID_Puesto, Fecha_Alta, Fecha_Baja FROM personal 
                  WHERE Nombre LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'
                  OR Apellidos LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'";
    }
        
    $authors=[];
    $errors=['data'=>false];

    $getAuthors = $db->query($query);

    if ($getAuthors->num_rows > 0){
        while($data = $getAuthors->fetch_assoc()){
            $authors[] = $data;
        }
        echo json_encode($authors);    
    }
    else{
        echo json_encode($errors);
    }
    
?>

script.js
window.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", () =>{
     const search = document.querySelector("#search");  //id = search
     const tableContainer = document.querySelector("#results tbody");  //id = results
     const resultsContainer = document.querySelector("#resultsContainer"); //id = resultsContainer
     //const errorsContainer = document.querySelector(".error-container");  //class = error-container
     const errorsContainer = document.querySelector("#errorContainer");  //id = error-container
     let search_criteria ="";      
    
     //Recoge lo escrito en el input y lo asigna a search_criteria
     if (search !== "") {
        search.addEventListener("input", event => {
            search_criteria = event.target.value.toUpperCase();            
            showResults();
        })
     }
     else {
        showResults();
     }
     
     //Enviar petición usando fetch

     const searchData = async ()=> {
        let formData = new FormData()
        formData.append("search_criteria", search_criteria);

        try {
            const response = await fetch("search_data.php", {
                method: "POST",
                body: formData
            });
            return response.json();
            
        } catch (error) {
            alert ("Hubo un error y no se puede procesar la solicitud");
        }                
        };

        const showResults = () => {
            searchData()
            .then(dataResults => {                
                console.log(dataResults);
                tableContainer.innerHTML = "";
                if (typeof dataResults.data !== "undefined" && !dataResults.data) {                                        
                    errorsContainer.style.display = "block";
                    errorsContainer.querySelector("p").innerHTML = "No hay resultados en la búsqueda: <span class='bold'>" + search_criteria + "</span>";
                    resultsContainer.style.display = "display";
                }
                else{
                    resultsContainer.style.display = "block";
                    resultsContainer.style.display = "";                        

                        for (author of dataResults){
                            const row = document.createElement("tr")
                            row.innerHTML = `
                            <td>${author.DNI}</td>                            
                            <td>${author.Nombre.toUpperCase().replace(search_criteria, "<span class='bold'>$&</span>")}</td>
                            <td>${author.Apellidos.toUpperCase().replace(search_criteria, "<span class='bold'>$&</span>")}</td>
                            <td>${author.Fecha_Alta}</td>
                            <td>${author.Fecha_Baja}</td>
                            `
                                                                    
                            tableContainer.appendChild(row);
                        }
                }
            })
        }
    });


Siempre sé descriptivo/a en el título de tu pregunta. Esto ayuda a que se comprenda resumidamente el problema que estás teniendo. Fijate la enorme diferencia entre el título anterior y el actual.

Si cambias esto:
    if ($search_criteria == ""){
    $query = "SELECT * FROM personal";
}
else {
    $query = "SELECT DNI, Nombre, Apellidos, ID_Puesto, Fecha_Alta, Fecha_Baja FROM personal 
              WHERE Nombre LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'
              OR Apellidos LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'";
}

Por algo así:
    if ($search_criteria != "" && $search_criteria != NULL){
    $query = "SELECT DNI, Nombre, Apellidos, ID_Puesto, Fecha_Alta, 
             Fecha_Baja FROM personal 
              WHERE Nombre LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'
              OR Apellidos LIKE '%" .$search_criteria. "%'";
     }
     else {
           $query = "SELECT * FROM personal";
     }

De igual forma, primero debes asegurarte que entre el POST, puedes darle un valor desde el inicio para saber si está entrando en cuanto entras a la página, algo así:
$search_criteria = 'valor';

El POST si lo recibe porque la búsqueda que hago si que me la muestra. Lo que no consigo es que me muestre es la búsqueda inicial

Ya intentaste cambiando la condición a como la puse?
Porque en un inicio $search_criteria puede no ser igual a "", si no que sea NULL

Otra cosa que puedes intentar es haciendo que te imprima la $query poniendo echo $query;
